# How do you check the state of a radio button in Symfony 1.4 functional testing

Tags: symfony1, functional-testing

In Symfony 1.4 I am trying to write a functional test that verifies a radio button is selected when the page renders.
The HTML appears as follows

```
<input id="plant_type_mangrove" type="radio" value="Mangrove" name="plant_type" checked="yes">
```

And following what I've seen in examples for select lists I expected this to work

```
$browser->with('response')->begin()->   
    checkElement('#plant_type_mangrove[checked="yes"]')->
end();
```

but it always fails.

How to I verify that a radio button is selected?

Comment: Have you tried `checkElement('#plant_type_mangrove:checked]')` ?

Comment: I have now. Both checked and selected come back with "unrecognized selector"

Comment: This try something like `checkElement('input[id="flight_flight_status_OPEN"][checked]')->`